# M2E-Pro The product with the same Merchant SKU is being listed now. SKU must be unique for each Amazon item

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm retriving the above error , while listing products on M2E-Pro. The error seems to appear only on some products. But interesting that on Amazon I've no products at all. I deleted them all. So it's still saying that the SKU should be unique. All the products have unique SKU on Magento. 
So what the error stands for. And how could I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of work I just discovered the reason of the problem. Will pass you an email that I sent to the support of M2E-pro:

--- So, I think that today I should help You. I asked you for support 2 days ago about:
"The product with the same Merchant SKU is being listed now. SKU must be unique for each Amazon item".
Basically this error message may generate misunderstandings in certain circumstances. Assume the case that for some reasons the server fails to list the products (the script or the server will shutdown) or in my case an HTTP error 504 was generated by NGINX due to some internal TIMEOUT settings. The Lock_Item table of M2E-Pro will mantain forever my SKUS locked. This is the error. If this happens, the call to the function getQueueOfSkus() in code\community\Ess\M2ePro\Model\Connector\Amazon\Product\List\multiple.php file at line 641 returns the locked queue. So any attempt to relist, list or doing whatever with the same product skus will return the error above, which is basically not the exact description of what is going on. Only a cleanup of the Lock_item table could solve the problem.  Solution: Do some cleanings if possible in the cronjob, just to verify that all is ok. The company for which I'm working was stuck for 3 days because of this error.---